# IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ClassName is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm, spring-annotations

I am getting this error in Spring MVC:

> **Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: SampleClass is**
> not mapped sampleClass.

Below is my `DaoClass` function where I mapped `SampleClass` with `SampleClass`  table

```java
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
public List<SampleClass> getData()
{
   Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
   List <SampleClass> sampleClass = session.createQuery("from SampleClass",SampleClass.class).list();
            
   return sampleClass;
}
```

Even the table name is the same and the column name is the same as sampleClass property.

In the sample class I used annotations for mapping:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class SampleClass {
    
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Id
    private  int id;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String aname;
    
}
```

I went through many solutions nothing resolved mine.
Is there any issue related to dependency versions?
One more thing `@Entity` is showing deprecated any other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One more thing @Entity is showing deprecated any other alternative?

It looks like you use `org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` instead of the `javax.persistence.Entity`.

So, correct your mapping in this way:

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class SampleClass {

}
```

Comment: that was a typo! Please consider my class name as "SampleClass "